# How disable "defer" in angular build?

Tags: angular, typescript

When i build my angular project, the compiler put the "defer" attribute in "index.html" but i need to disable this. Is it possible?

Im using angular 8.0.0.

```
<pre>
    <script src="runtime.js" defer>
</pre>
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove this?

Comment: I need to embed the angular application in another ERP application. In previous version the angular CLI did not insert the "defer" in index.html and works fine.

Comment: What happens when you try to embed the application, do you get any errors? What makes you think `defer` is the issue?

Comment: Any error in console or network. Only not work.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue - angular 8 build also come with defer attribute with the script tag , issue is that is not compatible with html 5 integration on Theamleaf resolver